# Как docker распределяет контейнеры при добавлении новой машины в swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Прохожу [docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#create-a-cluster).

Создал две VM, собрал их в swarm. Командой `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml <stackname>` задеплоил на них стек из 6 контейнеров. На каждую VM попало по три контейнера.

Добавил ещё одну VM в swarm, выполнил `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml <stackname>`, ожидаю что контейнеры перераспределятся на добавленную машину, чтобы на всех машинах их стало по два, но это не происходит.

Вопросы:

- Почему контейнеры не перераспределяются? Понятно, что «потому что такая логика запрограммирована в `docker stack deploy`». Но почему логика именно такая — так безопаснее, выгоднее...?
- Есть ли способ форсированно перераспределить контейнеры, как будто я в первый раз делаю `docker stack deploy`?

Да, я заметил, что новые контейнеры будут размещаться в первую очередь на VM3, пока их не будет везде примерно поровну. Вопрос о том,  почему уже существующие не «переехали».

Из [документации](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#iterating-and-scaling-your-app):

> You can join any machine, physical or virtual, to this swarm, using the same `docker swarm join` command you used on `myvm2`, and capacity will be added to your cluster. Just run `docker stack deploy` afterwards, and your app will take advantage of the new resources.

---

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: <name>/<repo>:<tag>
    deploy:
      replicas: 6
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Команды для воспроизведения

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm2
docker-machine ssh myvm1 "docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.99.100"
docker-machine ssh myvm2 "docker swarm join --token <token> 192.168.99.100:2377"
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml <stackname>

# видим, что контейнеры распределены поровну
docker stack ps <stackname>

# теперь создаем ещё одну машину
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm3
docker-machine ssh myvm3 "docker swarm join --token <token> 192.168.99.100:2377"
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml <stackname>

# видим, что контейнеры не перераспределились
docker stack ps <stackname>
```